# Error when calling a SP from another one

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created the following MySQL SP successfully..

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `Common_Proc_Create_NewId`
(
 TableName VARCHAR(250),
 ColumnName VARCHAR(150),
 OUT ReturnId BIGINT
)
BEGIN


DECLARE varb BIGINT;

SET @NewId:= CONCAT('SELECT (IFNULL(MAX(', ColumnName, '), 0) + 1) INTO ', varb, ' FROM ', TableName);

PREPARE Stmnt FROM @NewId;

EXECUTE Stmnt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE Stmnt;

SET ReturnId =  varb;

END$$
```

But when this was called from another SP I got the following error:

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

***Calling SP***

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `Masters_Proc_Create_BranchType`(
 BranchTypName VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN

    CALL Common_Proc_Create_NewId('Masters_BranchType', 'BranchTypeId', @Id);

    INSERT INTO Masters_BranchType (BranchTypeId, BranchTypeName) VALUES (@Id, BranchTypName);

    SELECT @Id;
END$$
```

Comment: Does your `Common_Proc_Create_NewId` executes fine?

Comment: No Rahul. The error is bcoz of Common_Proc_Create_NewId

Comment: @Rahul  => I think the error is in the following stmt..

Comment: SET @NewId:= CONCAT('SELECT (IFNULL(MAX(', ColumnName, '), 0) + 1) INTO ', varb, ' FROM ', TableName);

Comment: @Rahul     Thanks for ur reply Rahul.. Bt why varb is not getting any value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your stored procedure `Common_Proc_Create_NewId` the part `into varb` was causing the issue and think it's not allowed that way in a prepared statement (not sure though). Instead the way you are doing, try like below and it works fine (a sample code included)

```
delimiter // 
CREATE PROCEDURE dynamic1(IN tbl VARCHAR(64), IN col VARCHAR(64), OUT ret int)
BEGIN
    SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT @i := (IFNULL(MAX(', col, '), 0) + 1)  FROM ', tbl);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    set ret = @i;
END
//
delimiter ;

call dynamic1('test1','col',@id);
select @id;
```